# Adicionar linha jquery sem alterar valor anterior

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma row com quatro inputs conforme a imagem, que ao clicar no botão é adicionada uma nova linha. O problema é que a cada inserção o valor do select volta ao valor do primeiro option, não mantendo o valor antigo selecionado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código de adicionar linhas

```
  addPlanRow = function() { 

  cols = "";
  newRow = $("<tr>");
  cols +=  '<td class="b-n">'+
               '<div class="input-group">'+
               '<select class="form-control input-sm rule-choose-plan-doctor" name="form_plan[]">'+
                  '<option>Selecione qual plano de saúde</option>'+
                  ''+listPlansDoctor()+''+
               '</select>'+
               '</div>'+
            '</td>'+                                    
            '<td class="b-n">'+
               '<div class="input-group">'+
                  '<div class="input-group-addon"><i class="ti-search"></i></div>'+
                  '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm search-code-plan" placeholder="Pesquisar código" name="form_code_plan[]"> '+
               '</div>'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td class="b-n"> '+
               '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm insert-value-code" name="form_value_code[]"'+
               'onKeyPress="reais(this,event)" onKeyDown="backspace(this,event)">'+
            '</td>'+
            '<td class="b-n">'+
               '<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm insert-factor-multiplier" placeholder="Fator Multiplicador" name="form_multiplier_factor[]">'+
            '</td>'+                       
            '<td class="b-n">'+

               '<div class="btn btn-sm btn-success"  onclick="addPlanRow(this)" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </div>'+
               '<div class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="removePlanRow(this)"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> </div>'+
            '</td>';           


  newRow.append(cols);

  $("#input_configurations_plan").append(newRow);

  return false;
```

Função que itera o select

```
 listPlansDoctor = function(){

$.ajax({
  type:'post',  
  dataType: 'json',  
  url: getUrl + 'json/list_plans_doctor',
  success: function(dados){
    var plans = '';
    $.each(dados, function(key, value){
        plans += '<option value="' + value.id_hp + '.' + value.name + '.' + value.choose_types + '">' + value.name + '</option>';
    });

     $('.rule-choose-plan-doctor').empty().append(plans);

  }
});
```

Como eu posso manter o valor do select anterior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É que você está usando uma classe geral no seletor:

```
$('.rule-choose-plan-doctor').empty().append(plans);
```

Isso irá alterar todos os elementos com a classe `.rule-choose-plan-doctor`. Você teria que pegar apenas o último elemento com essa classe. Basta adicionar `:last` no seletor:

```
$('.rule-choose-plan-doctor:last').empty().append(plans);
```

Comment: valeu @Sam, nossa e pesquisei tanto sobre, com certeza não procurei da forma correta. Obrigado mesmo